# How to regenerate deleted pom.xml file and add dependency in eclipse automatically

Tags: maven

I mistakenly deleted my pom.xml file from my application. I created new pom.xml but dependencies are not added.

How can I add already generated dependencies automatically in created pom.xml file.

Comment: are you using any IDE or version control system, where you pushed your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using eclipse, you can try to go to:

> C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\yoursAPP\yoursAPP\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

And there you will find something like:

> YourAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom

which is your Pom file, just rename it

I know, that question is old, but maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has this feature: Right Click on project -> Restore from Local History

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. go for
Right Click on project -> Restore from Local History and their you can find pom.xml.